# Way to draw NSString on a curved path?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uilabel, curve

I have been looking for any example code for drawing a `UILabel` (or just an `NSString` or something) on a curved path, but have come up empty handed.

Does anyone know whether it's possible to draw text on a curved path, like a circle or something, without using separate pieces of graphics for every single letter?

Comment: I sure can't think of anything built in that would allow you to do this without drawing each letter individually.  You may have to go that route.

Comment: Can you point me in a direction to how this is done, so I can check out whether it's worth it? It's not a crucial aspect of my project, but more to make the UI just a tad nice. Thank you.