# Draw a text around the circle

Tags: iphone

How i can draw a text around the border of a circle?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528101/way-to-draw-nsstring-on-a-curved-path

Answer (score 1):

Draw each letter at a time, rotating the drawing context step by step, in increments suiting your circle's radius. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930313/how-do-i-draw-an-nsstring-at-an-angle)'s how to perform the rotation.